# Strange Latex page breaks (too much whitspace)

Tags: line, page

I'm having weird page break issues which look like some kind of bug to me. I added a screenshot to visualize the problem. Can someone explain, why `LaTeX` wouldn't add another line to the page above? It leaves a huge gap instead, which should be avoided IMHO.

[image]

Comment: There's no chance for us to diagnose the situation (and reach your apparent conclusion, that LaTeX should be able to cram in another at the bottom of the first page) unless you provide some hard information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? Which font, and which font size? How wide and tall is the text block? How deep is the footer part of the page?

Comment: You also need to keep in mind that LaTeX is very holistic in its decision making. It measureness the "badness" of certain typesetting decisions and will sometimes choose to do one thing that has lesser badness if it avoids even greater badness elsewhere. In this case, moving one more line on to one page might create a window or orphan later in the document, for example.

Comment: Honestly? Your document looks fine to me, even a bit cramped as it is. I'd probably leave a bigger footer, but it's hard to tell without seeing whole pages.

Comment: the space before footnotes is `\skip\footins` what have you set it to?

Comment: Without a minimum working example (MWE) using the `lipsum` package (to make the dummy text) the question is just a guessing game without clues. Coming to play to this, I would say that LaTeX is simply avoiding  to start the second page with two orphan lines. Search about widow and orphan penalties in LaTeX.